# Adding objects to a vector from a text file

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to read a start.txt file which will be used to create robot objects of a robot class and then i aim to add these objects to a vector. The start.txt file is formatted as such

```
1 1 1 0                                                                                                  
2 2 60 -93
3 3 30 45
```

Where the first int on each line is the robot id and the next int is the team number followed by the starting x position and y position.
my robot.h file is

```
class robot {
    
private:
    const int _id; // Robot ID
    const int _team; // Robot Team
    int _posX; // X coordinate of robot in beginning
    int _posY; // Y coordinate of robto in beginning

    
public:
    
    // initialize robot info
    robot(int w, int x, int y, int z); 
    // id of the robot
    const int id() const { return _id; }
    //team of the robot
    const int team() const { return _team; }
    //x coordinate of the robot
    const int posX() const { return _posX; }
    //y coordinate of the robot
    const int posY() const { return _posY; }
    // add a robot
    void add_robot(robot r);
    // print the details of all robots currently in the system
    void show() const;
    
};
```

The corresponding robot.cpp file is as follows

```
vector<robot> robots;

robot::robot(int w, int x, int y, int z) : _id(w), _team(x), _posX(y), _posY(z) {}

//add a robot to the vector
void robot::add_robot(robot r) {
    robots.push_back(r);
}

//show all robots currently in the vector
void robot::show() const {
    for (const robot& r : robots)
    {
        cout << r.id() << " " << r.team() << " " << r.posX() << " " << r.posY() << "\n";
    }
}
```

in my main.cpp this is how i have attempted to read the file and add to a vector:

```
int main() {
    vector<robot> r;

    int robotID;
    int teamNo;
    int startPosX;
    int startPosY;

    ifstream startFile;
    startFile.open("start.txt");
    //Check for error
    if (startFile.fail()) {
        cout << "connection to file not established";
    }

    else {


        while (startFile >> robotID >> teamNo >> startPosX >> startPosY) {
            robot r1{robotID,teamNo,startPosX,startPosY,};
            //r.add_robot(r1); // this is what i attempted before
            r.push_back(r1);
        }
        
    }
```

what (i think) i am doing is going through each line and creating a new robot object with the values on that line , i then attempted to use my add_robot function to add these objects to my vector `r.add_robot(r1)` which i defined at the start of main `vector<robot>r` however this kept giving me an error so i ended up not using that function and just doing `r.push_back(r1)` my problem then arises when i try to use any functions i made earlier for example if i type`r.show()` i would get an error [error message][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uv93.png.

have i added objects to the vector from the file in the right way or is the problem else where in my approach.

Comment: You seem to be really confused about how class methods work. You have to call them on a particular instance.

Comment: Why is `add_robot()` part of the `robot` class? `robot` shouldn't know anything about the `vector` of robots. And you don't need a `robot` reference (`this`) to add a robot to the list.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly:
`add_robot()` and `show()` are member functions of the class `Robot` and not the `vector<Robot>` that you have defined in `main.cpp`.

Taking input from `txt` file is correct and it would work. Another suggestion:

```
while (startFile >> robotID >> teamNo >> startPosX >> startPosY) {        
    r.push_back({robotID,teamNo,startPosX,startPosY});
}
```